# Problems with replacing PixelData of Dicom file using Pydicom

Tags: arrays, conv-neural-network, pydicom

I am trying to replace the PixelData of a CT dicom slice with another array translated by a CNN model from the original. The new array has the same dimension as the original, while I want to keep all metadata and tags unchanged. My code is like this:

```
img = pydicom.dcmread('input.dcm')
array = machine_learning_model(img.pixel_array)
img.PixelData = array.tobytes()
img.save_as('output.dcm')
```

However, the output image is distorted geometrically (the image on top). I am sure the output array is geometrically correct as it can be correctly displayed before inserting into the dicom file. Can anyone tell me why? Thank you.[image]

Comment: It looks like your data has not the same dimensions as the original, most likely the size of each voxel value. Note that for CT mostly each voxel has 2 bytes (e.g. BitsAllocated is 16) - make sure your data has the same layout.

Comment: You can easily check this by comparing the size of the original PixelData against your newly set data.

Comment: Yes you are right. I forgot about the image cropping when feeding the original array into the machine learning model. So the original array has larger dimension than the output array. I solved the problem by changing the Rows and Columns tag of the dicom together with the PixelData. Thank you so much.